# AngularJS: How to clear cache after load view in ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I have small probelm: 
How do you clear the cache after you load a view in ui-router in AngularJS.
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i have jet one question how to reload current view after load it

Answer (score 0):

```html
app.controller('mainController', function($scope,$templateCache,$rootScope){
$scope.btnUpdate = function(){
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
$templateCache.removeAll();
});
}
});
```